# Apache Tomcat 9 Subprocess https-openssl-n high CPU usage

Tags: openssl, tomcat9

Does anyone know what are some reasons of the https-openssl-n long running processes in tomcat.  Below is the example output of the tomcat subprocess using command `top -n 1 -H -p 422`.  And does any know if it is safe to use linux `kill` command to terminate these stuck processes?

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    491 tomcat    20   0 5026072   2.6g  20044 R  73.3  34.4   1363:26 https-openssl-n
    490 tomcat    20   0 5026072   2.6g  20044 R  53.3  34.4   1372:33 https-openssl-n
   3379 tomcat    20   0 5026072   2.6g  20044 R  46.7  34.4   1386:57 https-openssl-n
   3516 tomcat    20   0 5026072   2.6g  20044 R  20.0  34.4   1396:43 https-openssl-n
    422 tomcat    20   0 5026072   2.6g  20044 S   0.0  34.4   0:00.00 java
    426 tomcat    20   0 5026072   2.6g  20044 S   0.0  34.4   0:22.08 java
```

Comment: I did a heapdump for the tomcat process with jcmd command tool and analyzed the heapdump with the Eclipse Memory Analyzer.  I found that this is a normal https-openssl-nio thread.  The root cause was a bad piece of the code cause a recursive loop cause the thread to stuck.

Comment: And I did try to kill the child process and that cause Tomcat restarted itself.  So, will not suggest to run kill command if you are on production environment.  Perform a safe restart instead.

Comment: Hi Was this a recursive loop in your code or in some tomcat code?

Comment: @Bradley Yes, you are right on target.  I was about to create a heap dump and found the recursive loop.  But I forget to post the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a recursive loop bug in our application.  We used jcmd command line tool to export the heap dump for the Tomcat process.

```
jcmd <pid> GC.heap_dump <file-path>
```

Then, we opened the heap dump with Memory Analyzer (MAT) from https://eclipse.dev/mat/ to find the long running process.  We were able to locate the recursive thread and make a code change to fix the bug.